# Наложение изображения на изображение в виджете

Tags: android, android-layout

Нужно получить такую кнопку:

[image: Скриншот кнопки]

Зеленый квадрат был добавлен путем параметра:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/green_square"
```

А вот как теперь на этот зеленый квадрат наложить изображение?

И помимо всего, изображение в разрешении *512х512px*, должно автоматически ресайзится до установленного значения *dp*.

Возможно ли это как-то реализовать?

Comment: Почему квадрат и круг должны устанавливаться отдельно? Почему нельзя нарисовать одно изображение - круг в квадрате и установить его через `android:drawableLeft` ?

Comment: Можно эту кнопку на 2 разбить - квадратную с изображением (квадрат + картинка), и справа прямоугольную, обе кнопки положить в контейнер (Linear или Relative layout), бордюр сделать с помощью бекграунда у контейнера.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй из кода ставить drawable left.

```
// Prepare drawables
Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_twitter);
ColorDrawable background = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
// Create parent drawable 
LayerDrawable parentDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{background, icon});
// Set size for parent drawable
parentDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
// Set parent to textview
test.setCompoundDrawables(parentDrawable, null, null, null);
```